# Rviz errors out with an "X Window System error"

Tags: rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When I run the command

```
$ rosrun rviz rviz
```

It fails with:

```
The program 'rviz' received an X Window System error.
This probably reflects a bug in the program.
The error was 'BadLength (poly request too large or internal Xlib length erro'.
(Details: serial 17 error_code 16 request_code 153 minor_code 17)
(Note to programmers: normally, X errors are reported asynchronously;
that is, you will receive the error a while after causing it.
To debug your program, run it with the --sync command line
option to change this behavior. You can then get a meaningful
backtrace from your debugger if you break on the gdk_x_error() function.)
```

It seemed to happen out of nowhere. It was working before.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11605/rviz-errors-out-with-an-%22x-window-system-error%22/) by [emerson](https://answers.ros.org/users/970/emerson/) on ROS Answers with karma: 71 on 2011-10-19

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

yesterday,this problem occur,and i try to restart my PC so many time but problem still there.
today,when i use the ubuntu(10.04) ,the "Update Manager" pop a window to tell us to update,i do so.
then i try to run rviz again,awesome it works!!

ok,i still don't how the problem is solved,but it works anyway.

---

Originally posted by [emerson](https://answers.ros.org/users/970/emerson/) with karma: 71 on 2011-10-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have this problem as well on my laptop. The practical answer is to restart rviz a couple of times.

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2011-10-20

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I had this same problem after updating Ubuntu. I came across this related answer and tried the suggestion and it worked:

http://answers.ros.org/question/2109/rviz-in-ros-electric

Basically I did sudo rm /usr/lib/libGL.so* and it worked.

---

Originally posted by [Corey Montella](https://answers.ros.org/users/45/corey-montella/) with karma: 63 on 2011-10-21

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Asomerville](https://answers.ros.org/users/351/asomerville/) on 2011-10-21**:
I would warn against removing libraries using `rm`. It is immensely much preferred to remove them via the package system if possible. At the very least, always back up the files you are going to delete so that you can undo if necessary.